# How to use append in a second for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, web-scraping, append

So I am using append to extend my list of scraped apartments. In this code I run in to a problem, because I have created second for loop to change the page in the website. So first for loop gives new page to the next for loop to scrape. But when its done with one page it just overwrites the last list. What I am doing wrong?

```
for page in range(1, 4):  # Gives new page to scrape

  r = requests.get( url + str(page))      
  soup = bs(r.content)
  apartments = soup.select(".ListPage__cardContainer__39dKQ")
  base_path = "https://www.etuovi.com"
  x = []
  apartment_list = []

  for index ,apartment in enumerate(apartments):

    if index == 2:  # Just to not scrape every item
      break

    relative_path = apartment.a['href']
    full_path = base_path + relative_path
    id_number = apartment.a['id']
    apartment_list.append(get_apartment_data(full_path))   #This works for one page


x.append(apartment_list)     # Tried to make this work.. Think one list should be enaught.
```

And the functions:

```
def get_content_value(info_list_data):

  if info_list_data.find("li"):
  return [li.get_text(" ", strip=True).replace("\xa0", "").replace("€", "").replace("/ kk", 
  "").replace("\n", "") for li in info_list_data.find_all("li")]

  else:
  return info_list_data.get_text(" ", strip=True).replace("\xa0" , "").replace("€", "").replace("/ 
  kk", "").replace("\n", "")
```

Last:

```
def get_apartment_data(url):

  r = requests.get(url)      
  soup = bs(r.content)
  all_info_list = soup.find_all(class_ = "CompactInfoRow__infoRow__2hjs_ flexboxgrid__row__wfmuy")

  for info_list in all_info_list:
 
    info_list.prettify()

  info = {}
  for index, info_list in enumerate(all_info_list):

    content_key = info_list.find(class_ = "flexboxgrid__col-xs-12__1I1LS flexboxgrid__col-sm-4__3RH7g 
    ItemHeader__itemHeader__32xAv").get_text(" ", strip=True)
    content_value = get_content_value(info_list.find(class_ = "flexboxgrid__col-xs-12__1I1LS 
    flexboxgrid__col-sm-8__2jfMv CompactInfoRow__content__3jGt4"))
    info[content_key] = content_value

return info
```

Comment: Did you mean to indent ‘x.append(apartment_list)’?

Answer (score 0):

```
for page in range(1, 4):  # Gives new page to scrape

  r = requests.get( url + str(page))      
  soup = bs(r.content)
  apartments = soup.select(".ListPage__cardContainer__39dKQ")
  base_path = "https://www.etuovi.com"
  x = []
  apartment_list = []

  for index ,apartment in enumerate(apartments):

    if index == 2:  # Just to not scrape every item
      break

    relative_path = apartment.a['href']
    full_path = base_path + relative_path
    id_number = apartment.a['id']
    apartment_list.append(get_apartment_data(full_path))   #This works for one page


x.append(apartment_list.copy())
```

You need to use the `copy()` method to make an independent copy. Otherwise each time you make a new apartment_list, it will change in your x list too. Like twins lists.

More generally:

```
x = []
lst = [1,2,3]

x.append(lst)

print (x)

lst[0] = 0

x.append(lst)

print (x)
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3]]

[[0,2,3],[0,2,3]]
```

The right way is:

```
x = []
lst = [1,2,3]

x.append(lst.copy())

print (x)

lst[0] = 0

x.append(lst.copy())

print (x)
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3]]

[[1,2,3],[0,2,3]]
```